# VB.net Validate Textbox using IDataErrorInfo When click on Button

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want to create a simple Login system using WPF MaterialDesign control. I want to validate Username and Password When Click on Login button and check if that fields are empty or not. here is my view:

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel Background="White" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Text="SignIn" FontSize="30" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,60,0,30"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="32,0,32,0">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Person" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                <TextBox 
                    x:Name="username" 
                    Text="{Binding Username, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                    materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Username" 
                    Width="215"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="32,20,32,0">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Key" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Password}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Password"  Width="215"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,40,0,0">
                <Button Content="LOGIN" Width="100" Margin="0,0,20,0"  Command="{Binding LoginCmd}"/>
            </StackPanel>


            <TextBlock Text="Create New Account" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Cursor="Hand"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Here is my viewmodel

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class LoginViewModel
    Inherits BaseViewModel
    Implements IDataErrorInfo

    Dim LoginUser As Login

    'Get username and password
    Private _username As String
    Private _password As String

    Public Sub New()
        LoginUser = New Login
    End Sub

    Public Property Username As String
        Get
            Return _username
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _username = value
            RaisedPropertyChanged("Username")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Password As String
        Get
            Return _password
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _password = value
            RaisedPropertyChanged("Password")
        End Set
    End Property



    Dim _cmd As New CustomCommand(AddressOf CheckLogin)

    Public ReadOnly Property LoginCmd As ICommand
        Get
            Return _cmd
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub CheckLogin()
        LoginUser.Username = _username
        LoginUser.Password = _password

        If LoginUser.CheckLogin = True Then
            MsgBox("Successfull")
        Else
            MsgBox("Not Successfull")
        End If
    End Sub


    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(columnName As String) As String Implements IDataErrorInfo.Item
        Get
            Dim errorMsg As String = String.Empty
            If "Username" = columnName Then
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Username) Then
                    errorMsg = "Username can't be blank!"
                End If
            End If

            Return errorMsg
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property [Error] As String Implements IDataErrorInfo.Error
        Get
            Return String.Empty
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

But the problem is when I run that code it shows "Username can't be blank!". But I want to show the error message only when user clicks on the "Login" button. So how to solve this?

Comment: Add a flag. Bool UserInput or whatever. Set that initially to false. Check the flag in your error handling and don't raise any errors when false.  Set the flag true in your command.

Comment: You could implement the [INotifyDataError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) and raise the `ErrorsChanged` event.